# Selected checkboxes disabling using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Have datatable and checkboxes. If we select checkboxes across all pages(few records in each page), I'm able to get all JSON data of the selected records, could any one suggest me how disable the selected checkboxes. tried below code for getting json data,

```
  fnGetJsonData() {
    const data = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked);

    const mappedData = data.map(d => ({
      id: d.id,
      firstName: d.firstName,
      lastName: d.lastName,
      dropdown: d.dropdown
    }));
    this.persons.filter(f => f.checked); // after got json need to disable the checkboxes
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mappedData));
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-mra1xy)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a small trick to fulfill your task. you can check that below here Click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-le4zyz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)!